# Check for array in JS

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to check a value in JS that on page load is returned as a single-element array and after an ajax function returns as a string. I don't know why it's doing this but I'm trying to role with it.

So, using `console.log(value)` I get `array ['Scranton']` on page load, and the ajax even returns  `string "Scranton"`

When trying to check this variable, this does not work as I intended:

```
if ( value === 'Scranton' || value === ['Scranton']){
    ...
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Two different arrays with the same content are never equal: `[] === []` is `false`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/7837456/218196 for general solutions.

Comment: typeof value == 'String'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` for both an array and a string, so `value.indexOf("Scranton") !== -1` will work (just tested this on the console).

However you must first check for null/false/undefined or it will error.

```
if (value && value.indexOf("Scranton") !== -1) {}
```

EDIT: As Felix said, this will also be true for any string containing "Scranton". If this is a problem, then you can check for `indexOf == 0` instead, which will be true for any string starting with "Scranton". It really depends on your concrete problem if this solution fits you. Use with care.

Comment: That will be true for `"fooScrantonbar"` as well though.

Comment: You are right, perhaps he should check for 0 instead. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 3):

This would probably work but I would try and fix the underlying issue instead of working around it.

```
if ( value === 'Scranton' || value[0] === 'Scranton'){
    ...
}
```

Comment: for the record, this also worked. My choice of answer was merely a matter of preference. Thanks!

Comment: @PeteSorensen np, I upvoted the other answer I thought it was good.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (Object.prototype.toString.call(value) === '[object Array]') {
    if (value.indexOf('Scranton') != -1) {
        /*  */
    }
} else {
    if (value === 'Scranton') {
        /*  */
    }
}
```

Edit 1:

First, you need to check if "value" is an array. If it's an array and contains the string "Scranton", you can find it using `value.indexOf()`.
And if "value" is not an array, you can directly compare it with the string 'Scranton'.

Comment: Please, add some explanation to your answer. As it is now, it's been flagged as "low quality".

Answer (score 0):

What does "after an ajax function" mean? The page loads with a default variable that has been assigned an array value, and then an Ajax request is made, which changes this default variable, and instead of an array being assigned, it assigns a string? Assuming this "ajax function" changes the default variable to the response text from the server, there is your problem: Ajax--like any other request--is text-based, so it is a string. If you are responding to the Ajax request with a JSON *string*, built on the server, it needs to be parsed in the browser, so it can be reinterpreted as an array. See the [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) method.